# O que é o padrão Adapter?

Tags: java, design-pattern, adapter

O que é e como funciona o padrão Adapter em Java, estou tentando entender esse padrão pois irei utilizar o mesmo em um projeto.

Comment: É estranho você querer usar uma coisa que você não entende. Padrões não foram feitos para você escolher e usar. Eles foram feitos para usar quando existe a necessidade. E para saber se tem a necessidade é preciso entendê-lo.

Comment: Talvez o padrão esteja citado no documento de arquitetura, é comum quando um sistema ou parte dele é projetado em alto nível e a implementação delegada a outra equipe.

Comment: É projeto de faculdade, requisito do professor @bigown

Comment: Fazendo uma colinha básica no Stackoverlow. Brincadeira :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eh mais ou menos, mais pra entender msm, pq tenho q desenvolver um projeto nesse padrao

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Em resumo, o padrão de projetos *Adapter* consiste em adaptar a interface de uma classe ou objeto para ser usada de outra forma, porém sem alterar a interface ou implementação.

## Exemplo: persistência em diferentes serviços

Um caso comum é quando desenvolvemos um código *cliente* que pretende usar diversas fontes heterogêneas.

Por exemplo, você tem várias implementações capaz de ler e gravar arquivos de diversos serviços:

```
class DropBox {
    void upload(DropBoxFile dbFile) {}
    DropBoxFile download(String id) {} 
}

class AWS {
    void save(InputStream input, int id) {}
    InputStream restore(int id) {} 
}

class GoogleDrive {
    void send(byte[] data, String name) {}
    byte[] get(String name) {} 
}
```

Cada uma dessas classes está em uma biblioteca ou projeto diferente. Você não quer fazer alterações nem duplicar o código.

Agora imagine que você tem um sistema onde o usuário pode decidir em qual serviço os dados serão salvos. Uma saída é escrever um código procedural cheio de `if`s e `else`s cada vez que o sistema precisar usar um dos serviços disponíveis, exemplo:

```
if (dropbox) {
  //faz alguma coisa
} else if (aws) {
 //faz outra
} else if (drive) {
 // outra ainda
}
```

Mas você não vai querer isso várias vezes no sistema, mais o código necessário para converter os tipos do sistema para os tipos específicos dos serviços. Pense em quanta manutenção seria necessária para adicionar um novo serviço

Então podemos definir uma interface de persistência:

```
interface Persistencia {
    void gravar(File file);
    File ler(String id);
}
```

Todo o sistema seria implementado usando apenas esta interface. Uma maravilha do ponto de vista da Orientação a Objetos, sem `if`s, sem necessidade de alterar o código se algum serviço mudar.

Mas o problema não está completamente resolvido. As classes dos serviços que nós não queremos alterar não implementam nossa interface.

Então, para cada serviço, devemos implementar um adaptador. Por exemplo:

```
class DropBoxAdapter implements Persistencia {
  DropBox dropBox;
  DropBoxAdapter(DropBox dropBox) {
    this.dropBox = dropBox;
  }
  void gravar(File file) {
    dropBox.upload(new DropBoxFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
  }
  File ler(String id) {
    DropBoxFile dbFile = dropBox.download(id);
    return new File(dbFile.getLocalPath());
  }
}
```

Note que acabamos de criar uma classe que nos permite usar um objeto `DropBox` usando a interface `Persistencia`. Nós *adaptamos* a classe original conforme a interface desejada.

Outras implementações de *adapters* deveriam então ser providas para os outros serviços usando o mesmo princípio.

## Exemplo: melhorando código legado

Agora imagine que temos de dar manutenção num sistema mal projetado que implementa logs manualmente usando a seguinte classe:

```
class HomeMadeLog {
    public void log(int nivel, String mensagem, Throwable erro) {
        String s = formatarLog(nivel, mensagem, erro);
        adicionaLogNoArquivo(s);
    }
    private String formatarLog(...) { }
    private String adicionaLogNoArquivo(...) { }
}
```

Precisamos modernizar os logs usando um framework como Log4j, porém há milhares de chamadas ao método antigo e muitas delas são complicadas demais para simplesmente fazer uma substituição automática.

Além do mais, queremos evitar gerar alterar 99% dos arquivos do projeto, pois isso iria gerar um grande problema de conflitos no sistema de controle de versões para todos os demais desenvolvedores.

Uma solução é estender a classe `HomeMadeLog` de forma que ela seja um adaptador para o Log4j. Exemplo:

```
class HomeMadeLogToLog4jAdaptor extends HomeMadeLog {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger();
    @Override
    public void log(int nivel, String mensagem, Throwable erro) {
        if (nivel == 0) logger.debug(mensagem, erro);
        else if (nivel == 1) logger.info(mensagem, erro);
        else if (nivel == 2) logger.error(mensagem, erro);
    }
}
```

Agora basta fornecer uma instância de `HomeMadeLogToLog4jAdaptor` ao invés `HomeMadeLog` e todas as classes passarão a funcionar com o Log4j sem modificações.

## Considerações

Note que o principal trunfo do padrão de projetos *Adapter* é permitir reuso do código de forma consistente, mantendo compatibilidade com outras bibliotecas e versões anteriores de código.

Uma classe *adaptadora* nada mais é do que uma classe que implementa a interface que se deseja usar e delega a real execução para uma classe terceira que possui a implementação que desejamos usar.

Note também que meus exemplos são propositalmente simplificados. Alguns detalhes e complexidades que não são relacionados com o padrão em si foram omitidos para não complicar os exemplos.

Comment: No caso do exemplo do Log4j eu teria de necessariamente substituir a referência da classe HomeMadeLog pela HomeMadeLogToLog4jAdaptor em todas as classes, correto? Ou nesse exemplo você está considerando que quem fornece a HomeMadeLog seria um construtor estático e, nesse caso bastaria substituir o retorno pela subclasse?